# Flatten recursive array, "untree"'ing

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have an array,

```
$arr = Array(
    Array(
        'title' => 'Title 1',
        'id' => 1,
        'parent' => 0,
        'children' => [
            Array(
                'title' => 'Title 1.1',
                'id' => 4,
                'parent' => 1,
                'children' => [
                    Array(
                    'title' => 'Title 1.1.1',
                    'id' => 19,
                    'parent' => 4
                    ),      
                    Array(
                    'title' => 'Title 1.1.2',
                    'id' => 123,
                    'parent' => 4
                    )
                ]
            ),
            Array(
                'title' => 'Title 1.2',
                'id' => 4,
                'parent' => 1,
                'children' => [
                    Array(
                    'title' => 'Title 1.2.1',
                    'id' => 19,
                    'parent' => 4
                    )
                ]
            )
        ]
    ),
    Array(
        'title' => 'Title 2',
        'id' => 1,
        'parent' => 0
    )
);
```

Which I would like to "flatten" by "cutting" the children-nodes into separate items, giving me an array with these items in a one-level-array:

```
$arr = Array(
    Array(
        'title' => 'Title 1',
        'id' => 1,
        'parent' => 0
    ),
    Array(
        'title' => 'Title 1.1',
        'id' => 4,
        'parent' => 1
    ),
    Array(
        'title' => 'Title 1.1.1',
        'id' => 19,
        'parent' => 4
    ),
    Array(
        'title' => 'Title 1.1.2',
        'id' => 123,
        'parent' => 4
    ),           
    Array(
        'title' => 'Title 1.2',
        'id' => 4,
        'parent' => 1
    ),
    Array(
        'title' => 'Title 1.2.1',
        'id' => 19,
        'parent' => 4
    ),
    Array(
        'title' => 'Title 2',
        'id' => 1,
        'parent' => 0
    )
);
```

Can anybody help me out here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: function traverseArray($array, $target = Array()) { 

        foreach($array as $key => &$value) { 
            if (isset($value['children'])) {
                return traverseArray($value); 
            } else {
                $target[] = $array;
            }
        }
        return $target;

    }

    $out = traverseArray($arr);
    print_r($out);

This iterates but leaves a pattern I cannot really understand how it's built up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you..

```
<?php
 function recursiveFind(array $items,&$return=array())
{
    foreach($items as $item){
        if(array_key_exists('children',$item)){
            $childs = $item['children'];
            unset($item['children']);
            array_push($return,$item);
            recursiveFind($childs,$return);

        }else{
            array_push($return,$item);
        }

    }
    return $return;
}

$arr = Array(
    Array(
        'title' => 'Title 1',
        'id' => 1,
        'parent' => 0,
        'children' => [
            Array(
                'title' => 'Title 1.1',
                'id' => 4,
                'parent' => 1,
                'children' => [
                    Array(
                    'title' => 'Title 1.1.1',
                    'id' => 19,
                    'parent' => 4
                    ),      
                    Array(
                    'title' => 'Title 1.1.2',
                    'id' => 123,
                    'parent' => 4
                    )
                ]
            ),
            Array(
                'title' => 'Title 1.2',
                'id' => 4,
                'parent' => 1,
                'children' => [
                    Array(
                    'title' => 'Title 1.2.1',
                    'id' => 19,
                    'parent' => 4
                    )
                ]
            )
        ]
    ),
    Array(
        'title' => 'Title 2',
        'id' => 1,
        'parent' => 0
    )
);
echo '<pre>';
print_r(recursiveFind($arr));
```

Comment: Sorry, you mind have missunderstood. I would need an one-level array. I edited my question and the expected output.

Comment: Thank you. we're getting closer, but not yet - I have unfortunately little use if the array is starting "farest out". I need it in the same order as provided, from top to bottom. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! Of course you'll get the vote, well deserved.

Answer (score -1):

Try this with 3 foreach:

foreach($arr as $a)
    {

```
echo $a['title'];
foreach($a['children'] as $b)
{
    echo $b['title'];
    foreach($b['children'] as $c)
    {
        echo $c['title'];
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Not a good idea. I have a) no clue how deep this might go. b) Don't want to repeat any code, especially as it's ment to do the same stuff no matter at what level.